# Populate two rows of a combobox with a query Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm working on an Access 2007 database and I'm having a problem with a query.

I have a table named Vehicles, which contains data such as ID, license plate and fuel type for each vehicle in it.
I'm trying to make a query which will populate a combobox in a Form with each vehicle's fuel type, based on the license plate chosen by the user beforehand.

The thing is, we have some some cars that work with two types of fuel and I cant' find a way to display them separately in the combobox.

So far it kinda works, code follows:

```
CheckDiesel: IIf([Diesel]="Yes";"Diesel";IIf([Gasoline] AND [Ethanol]="Yes";"Gasoline"+ "Ethanol";IIf([Ethanol]="Yes";"Ethanol";IIf([Gasoline]="Yes";"Gasoline";""))))
```

If you look at the second IIf, I have a condition for a bi-fuel car. I want to display Gasoline and Ethanol separately, each one in a row.

I've tried using "&Chr(10) Chr(13)&" and "\r\n" but I had no success so far.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Storing multiple pieces of data in a single field rarely ends well. A few options I see

1. A series of binary fields for gasoline type. So you'd have a True/false for gasoline, ethanol, and diesel. This is easy to show with checkboxes on the form.
2. If you know there will only be certain combinations, like if there will not be a 'diesel and ethanol' without gasoline, you can build it as a single value combobox.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but why it rarely ends well?

Comment: Because anything that touches the fields that store multiple pieces of data in a single cell needs to also be coded to handle multiple data values in a single cell. If you're the only developer of this database then it can work great, but if other people's databases will be touching your data, or if you plan to eventually pass this database to someone else as you move up, it's a lot of extra work to use that data. For example: A simple query of "Show me the vehicles that can use gasoline" goes from "If CanUseGasoline=True" to a paragraph to extract the gasoline entries.

Comment: I see... Thanks for explaining that up!

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need some VBA to do what you need to do. Try something like this:

```
Dim R as String
R=""
if (Me.Diesel) then R = R & "Diesel;"
if (Me.Gasoline) then R = R & "Gasoline;"
… {add any other types of fuel}
Me.MyComboBox.Rowsource = R
Me.MyComboBox.Requery
```

This can be added tot he form's OnCurrent event so it will update the combo box every time a new record is displayed.

If your form does not include the various fuel types as fields, either add them as hidden fields or use DLookup to read them off the table.

Comment: Hmmm this is an interesting way to make it. I'll try something, thanks!